# Android Studio not starting while upgrading to 3.0. in linux

Tags: android, terminal, android-studio-2.3, android-studio-3.0

This is the error being displayed.

> Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:254)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:509)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:128)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:100)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:180)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.WindowManager.getInstance(WindowManager.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshProgress.lambda$updateIndicators$0(RefreshProgress.java:66)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:343)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:869)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:666)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:637)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:215)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:174)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:153)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.processException(PluginManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.processException(IdeEventQueue.java:422)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:346)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:869)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:666)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:637)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:215)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:174)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:153)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.processException(PluginManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.processException(IdeEventQueue.java:422)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:346)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add an action twice: Stop (Stop process)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup.addAction(DefaultActionGroup.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.addToGroupInner(ActionManagerImpl.java:829)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processAddToGroupNode(ActionManagerImpl.java:825)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processReferenceNode(ActionManagerImpl.java:786)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processActionsChildElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:972)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerPluginActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.<init>(ActionManagerImpl.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache folders?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues redirects to stackoverflow.com, or what happened?

Comment: It sends me to issue tracker window where i have shared my problem. But no one is replying.

Comment: no answers found till yet